# lwuit autocomplete

Tags: java-me, autocomplete, nokia, lwuit

I am developing simple j2me lwuit application for nokia mobile and I want to add auto complete in the application but I did not get any components for the auto complete. Could anybody please help me for making auto complete in j2me using lwuit?